# An experiment of three independant outcomes it had.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The probability of each outcome(A,B,C) is in order p,q,r respectively. What is the probability that a series of length a outcomes of A are had before a series of length b outcomes of B. I cant seem to put this into coherent relations but was thinking a polinom, with each monom of at least $p^a$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is positive, you could look at a binomial random variable $X$ with $n=a+b-1$ and probability parameter $\dfrac{p}{p+q}$.

You are then interested in the probability $X \ge a$ which is $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=a}^{a+b+1} {a+b-1 \choose k} \frac{p^k \, q^{a+b-1-k}}{(p+q)^{a+b-1}}.$$

*Added:*

If you do not want to go down the binomial random variable route, then you can instead find the probability of $a-1$ As and $m$ Bs (with $m \lt b$) in any order, again ignoring any Cs, followed by a final A.  This is   $$\displaystyle p\sum_{m=0}^{b-1} {a+m-1 \choose a-1} \frac{p^{a-1} \, q^{m}}{(p+q)^{a+m-1}}$$ but I doubt it is any easier.

Comment: Problem is we still havent delt random variables its in the part of the book that deals with conditional probability..